# Difference between columns of ArrayType in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe with 2 ArrayType columns.
I want to find the difference between columns. column1 will always have values while column2 may have empty array.
I created following udf but it is not working

`df.show()` gives following records

**SampleData:**

```
["Test", "Test1","Test3", "Test2"], ["Test", "Test1"]
```

**Code:**

```
sc.udf.register("diff", (value: Column,value1: Column)=>{ 
                        value.asInstanceOf[Seq[String]].diff(value1.asInstanceOf[Seq[String]])          
                    })
```

**Output:**

```
["Test2","Test3"]
```

Spark version 1.4.1
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what was the result ?

Comment: it gives all values of `value`

Comment: can you paste sample data pls? ideally it should work

Comment: I hope you have used `collection.SeqLike.diff`

Comment: Please share example data and expected output.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram For this part I am using the only above UDF.... `import scala.collection.mutable.Seq` This is my import

Comment: please test your data in REPL as described in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `udf` to:

```
val diff_udf = udf { ( a:  Seq[String], 
                       b:  Seq[String]) => a diff b }
```

Then this works:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
df.withColumn("diff",
  diff_udf(col("col1"), col("col2"))).show
+--------------------+-----------------+------------------+
|                col1|             col2|              diff|
+--------------------+-----------------+------------------+
|List(Test, Test1,...|List(Test, Test1)|List(Test3, Test2)|
+--------------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

**Data**

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((List("Test", "Test1","Test3", "Test2"), 
                             List("Test", "Test1")))).toDF("col1", "col2")
```

Answer (score 1):

> column1 will always have values while column2 may have empty array.
>
> ***your comment*** : it gives all values of value – undefined_variable

#### Example1 :

lets see small example like this...

```
   val A = Seq(1,1)

 A: Seq[Int] = List(1, 1)

 val B = Seq.empty

 B: Seq[Nothing] = List()
    
A diff B

 res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 1)
```

if you do a `collection.SeqLike.diff` then you will get A value as shown in example.
As per scala, this is very much valid case since you told you are always getting `value` which is seq.

Also, reverse case is like this...

```
 B diff A

 res1: Seq[Nothing] = List()
```

if you use Spark udf for doing above as well then same results will come.

### EDIT : (if one array not empty case as you modified your example )

#### Example2 :

```
 val p = Seq("Test", "Test1","Test3", "Test2")

 p: Seq[String] = List(Test, Test1, Test3, Test2)

 val q = Seq("Test", "Test1")

 q: Seq[String] = List(Test, Test1)

 p diff q

 res2: Seq[String] = List(Test3, Test2)
```

This is what your expected output which is coming as given in your example.

### Reverse case : I think this is what you are getting which is not expected by you.

```
q diff p

 res3: Seq[String] = List()
```